# Timer anti cheat technique

Tags: android, ios, timer, anti-cheat

Let's say I'm developing a game and there exists such thing as respawn. The user may respawn after 15 minutes. Is there any common practice to avoid time cheating? I mean, nothing can stop user from changing system time and set it to future. I know, partially this can be resolved by using server side, but nothing can stop user from disabling the network at all. 
PS. the game is cross platform so the solution is interesting for both antroid and iOS. PS2. I know a couple of games that have the solution.

Answer (score 1):

For something like this you could simply start your own timer completely separate from the system time. If you start a 15 minute countdown when a player dies they won't be able to modify your internal timer. I'm not as familiar with iOS dev (NSTimer looks like a possibility) but I know in Android it's as easy as:

```
// create 30 second internal countdown timer
new CountDownTimer(30000, 3000) {

 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
     // store time remaining in database every 3 seconds in case user exits the game
     dbHelper.updateDeathTimer(millisUntilFinished);
 }

 public void onFinish() {
     // player respawns now
 }
}.start();
```

To combat the issue of players closing the game I would suggest you also set up your internal timer to cache its' current state in the database at a regular interval, say every 30 seconds or so if you were going to stick with a 15 minute timer.

Below is some psuedocode for what it might look like when a player exits the game while they are dead and our respawn timer was still in progress.

```
// When game resumes check database and begin updated death timer if necessary
onGameResume() {
    if(dbHelper.isUserDead()) {
        // resume respawn timer 
        new CountDownTimer(dbHelper.getRespawnTime(), 15000) {

          public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            // store time remaining in database every 15 seconds in case user exits the game
            dbHelper.updateDeathTimer(millisUntilFinished);
          }

          public void onFinish() {
            // player respawns now
          }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: it's a good idea, but if the app is killed by user - it won't work. correct?

Comment: @DeepThought To combat this you would need to stash the current state of the timer in some sort of persistent storage (DB) before the app is closed. And then of course retrieve and resume the timer when the app (or specific game within the app) is resumed.

Comment: it won't help me to detect how much time the app was inactive.

Comment: @DeepThought Just as a backup you could also set up your internal timer to cache its' current state in the database at a regular interval, say every 30 seconds or so if you were going to stick with a 15 minute timer.

Comment: @DeepThought Just curious, why do you need to know how long the app was inactive?

Comment: this is the only way to calculate the respawn time when the app is killed. isn't it?

Comment: @DeepThought No all you have to do is check the database to see what the last state of the game was, if the player was dead then you retrieve the last saved value for their countdown timer and start it back up. Does that make sense?

Comment: no it doesn't. let's consider the situation. it's 09:15 now and you've just lost all your lifes. the respawn timer started, we've recorded 09:15 to some local storage. next, you kill the app (remove it from memory), go to device date and time settings and set current time to 09:40. then you run the app again and what does it see? 09:40 - 09:15 is 25 minutes, it's time to respawn.

Comment: @DeepThought We're never looking at the current time to tell when the player died. It doesn't matter what time it is when a player has lost all of their lives, when they do we put a value in the DB to say that the player has died and will need to wait for the respawn timer. The respawn timer starts (our own 15 minute timer) and let's say every 30 seconds we update the time remaining on the respawn in the DB. If the user kills the app immediately after they die they can wait 40 days for all we care, when they open the app again we look in the DB and they still have 15 min left on their respawn.

Comment: ah, I see now. that should work, but it's not quite fair from the user's perspective:)

Comment: @DeepThought The ultimate implementation is in your hands ;), I just gave you a possible anti-cheat solution that you were asking for and now it's up to you to decide what to do with it or how to adapt it to your needs.

Comment: I would maybe use this method as a backup to something server-side. I would find it sort of unusual if the user was expected to keep the game active for the 15 minutes before they respawn. IIRC, most games don't require this. If I die, I should be able to close the game, open it 15 minutes later, and be able to play again.

Comment: @DangerZone Agreed, and if we're being realistic I don't know anyone that would play a game with a respawn timer of 15 minutes, IMHO anything longer than 30 seconds would be pushing most people's patience.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the time of the event (spawn in your case), and then run a timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate against it and see if it exceeds your limit (15 minutes).

The risk on the iOS side is that the app goes to the background and the timers stop.

Answer (score -1):

It's not actually the answer, but just an idea.
What if we use tickCount? Each operating system has this property.
For instance, [android.os.SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#elapsedRealtime()) in Android and 
[[NSProcessInfo processInfo].systemUptime](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSProcessInfo_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSProcessInfo/systemUptime) in iOS
They should give required values.